# GeoDjango nearest points query using MariaDB / MySql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mariadb, nearest-neighbor, geodjango

In my Django project I would to use MySQL and/or MariaDB.

I have an entity that contains latitude and longitude.

I have to implement a search to find all points nearest (by distance params) to a geoPoint.

Probably I have to use GeoDjango but I have some doubts about compatibility with MySQL and geo distance query. In particular I have read this [documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/) and Compatibility Tables (I not see `distance_lte` for MySQL: Have I to use this?)

Is possible to have this type of functionality in my project using MariaDB / MySQL and GeoDjango?

Can I have this feature efficiently?
Is preferable to use other DBMS for example PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

**Update** [MySQL 8+ handles long / lat directly](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/geography-in-mysql-8-0/). You need to use [Spatial Reference System SRID 4326](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/), also known as WGS 84, if you're working with GPS data.

MariaDB 10.3 and 10.6 do *not* have SRID 4326, so all you get is planar geometry.

To use the distance-measurement stuff in GeoDjango you'll need postgreSQL or MySQL 8: Earlier geospatial extensions (in 5.7 and earlier versions) doesn't support lat/long distance measurement. (My MySQL 5.7 doesn't have `information_schema.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS` or anything resembpling it. And MariaDB 10.3 and 10.6 don't have SRID 4326.

If you're not wedded to GeoDjango you can use MySQL. You'll need to do some work to make your lookups efficient.  See here.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

If you want to use geospatial, see here.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/using-mysqls-geospatial-extension-location-finder/

Comment: Is this still the case in 2022?

Comment: Please see my edit. You're good to go with MySQL 8+.

Comment: Do you know if MariaDB is also supporting this? I got strange distance calculations there

Comment: Actually, MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10.2 added SPATIAL to InnoDB.

Comment: I figured this out. `SELECT * FROM information_schema.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS  WHERE SRS_ID = 4326;` on MySQL 8 shows it has the SRID you want. `SELECT * FROM information_schema.SPATIAL_REF_SYS; on MariaDB (different info table name) shows it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think MariaDB has yet implemented `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE*()`, but such a function can be written.

Answer (score 1):

5 ways to do "find nearest" in MySQL/MariaDB:

1. Brute force -- very slow for big lists because of full table scan
2. `INDEX(lat, lat), INDEX(lng, lat)` -- order of magnitude faster
3. SPATIAL index (if available)
4. Partitioning -- turns lat into partitioning, giving more speed
5. Z-Order layout of index -- similar speed to Partitioning

Details: [*Find Nearest*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

It contains a function the equivalent to `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE()`, if needed.  (Yes it is slower.)